# An error message is thrown reading "cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined" whenever react native contacts is initiated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have tried every possible syntax possibility and have been at it for days. The error will persists and I can't help but wonder if it is a problem with the package itself. The name of the package is "react-native-contacts". Please assist if you are able to.

Comment: What is the current code that i throwing this error?

Comment: check line 37 of your code